# How to add pop up window on Grid.php action link?

Tags: magento-1.8, grid

I want to add popup link on Grid.php , i tried

```
      $this->addColumn('action', array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Action'),
            'width'     => '80',
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'    => 'getId',
            'actions'   => array(
                array(
                    'caption'   => Mage::helper('feedback')->__('Reply'),
                    'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                    'field'     => 'id',
                    'onclick' =>"return popitup('".$this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getId()))."')"
                )
            ),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'stores',
            'is_system' => true,
    ));
```

I want both below link same

```
<a href="http://localhost/magento/index.php/feedback/adminhtml_mymodule/edit/id/4/key/220a1ff8d9526bd40f43e79502897d3f/" onclick="return popitup('http://localhost/magento/index.php/feedback/adminhtml_mymodule/edit/id/mymoduleGrid/key/220a1ff8d9526bd40f43e79502897d3f/')">Reply</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
'onclick' =>"return popitup('".$this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getId()))."')"
```

with

```
'target'    => '_blank'
```

Comment: thanks @Marius, but i want to show only pop up window, just i want row id of table , as i had fetched all data into Grid. I tried array('id' => $this->getId())) instead of function getRowUrl($row). Stil unable to get result.                      In future i want to change popbox to lightbox.

Comment: Is there any way to fetch id of row at 'onclick' =>"return popitup('".$this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getId()))."')" this line.
'id' => $this->getId() just i want to change this line

Comment: Why not implementing your own JS file with an onclick handler, then you have the full control over the event object

Answer (score 1):

Magento has an attribute for this already -> 'popup'.

Replace:

```
'onclick' =>"return popitup('".$this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getId()))."')"
```

With:

```
'popup' => true
```

For more information on this check out:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Action
```

In the method _transformActionData() it says:

```
case 'popup':
     $action['onclick'] =
          'popWin(this.href,\'_blank\',\'width=800,height=700,resizable=1,scrollbars=1\');return false;';
                break;
```